# Negative Balance

Tags: function, plsql, aggregate

I have 3 tables. Account. Trans and Balance.

Sum(Amount) in Trans table equals balance at any given time for each account.

I need a query which checks that balance is negative for consecutive 3 months or more from today's date. (so sysdate whenever I would run this).

I was wondering how can I query where it would display account number and balance only if it is negative for consecutive 3 months or more regardless of when the transaction occur.

Tables:

```
Trans Table
Select * from trans where accountid = 1;

Transdate  Merchant    Amount   AccountID
10/1/16    Employer    50       1
10/4/16    Walmart     -20      1
10/7/16    Kroger      -50      1
```

Now, his account went negative -$20 on 10/7/2016.

```
Transdate  Merchant    Amount   AccountID
12/01/16   Employer    10       1
```

His Account is still negative. If I run the query today (01/16/2017) or later, his account should get picked up because he still has negative balance for at least 90 days.

```
Balance Table
```

It keeps only 1 record per Account. As of today, it shows the following:

```
AccountID    Balance    LastUpdate
1            -10        12/01/2016
```

LastUpdate is the same date as the last date of transaction in Trans Table for that Account.

Comment: Hi, how many records each account has(per day or per month)?

Comment: 10-15 transactions per account. And 50,000 accounts all together.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.  The top section just creates some test data...

```
 WITH 
 trans (transdate,merchant,amount,accountID)
 AS
 (SELECT sysdate-100,'A',100,1 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT sysdate-99,'B',-101,1 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT sysdate-91,'C',-50,1 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT sysdate-10,'D',30,1 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT sysdate-100,'E',100,2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT sysdate-99,'F',-100,2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT sysdate-91,'G',-50,2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT sysdate-10,'H',200,2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT sysdate-10,'I',100,3 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT sysdate-9,'J',-50,3 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT sysdate-8,'K',-75,3 FROM dual 
 )
SELECT DISTINCT
 accountId
FROM
 (SELECT
   accountid
  ,transdate
  ,amount
   --get the maximum balance in the dataset
  ,MAX(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY accountID) max_balance
  FROM
   --this query gets raw transaction data and calculates cumulative balance
   (SELECT
     accountid
    ,transdate
    ,amount
     --cumulative balance
    ,SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY accountID ORDER BY transdate)   balance   
     --works the dateof the next transaction - ths determines how long the balance is current 
    ,LEAD(transdate) OVER (PARTITION BY accountID ORDER BY transdate) - 1  bal_end_date
    FROM
     trans
   )
  WHERE 1=1
  --only interested in balances that are 'current' in the past three months
  AND bal_end_date >= ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-3)
 )
WHERE 1=1
--only want accounts where the maximum balance is negative
AND max_balance < 0
;
```

Comment: Please note that my solution can be improved by using the balances table to restrict the analysis to accounts that currently have a negative balance.  As it stands the query needs to look back at all transactions for an account to calculate the balance at any point in time- it's a waste of effort to do this for accounts where we know that the current balance is positive

Comment: Any feedback on this?